# Unknown symbols when I read file

Tags: c, file

I read file, but in the end of file i get unknown symbols:

```
int main()
{
        char *buffer, ch;
        int i = 0, size;
        FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
        if(!fp){
                printf("File not found!\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(fp);
        printf("%d\n", size);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); 
        buffer = malloc(size * sizeof(*buffer));
        while(((ch = fgetc(fp)) != NULL) && (i <= size)){
                buffer[i++] = ch;
        }
        printf(buffer);
        fclose(fp);
        free(buffer);
        getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `null` char at the end of buffer before you print:

```
while(((ch = fgetc(fp)) != NULL) && (i <= size)){
    buffer[i++] = ch;
}
buffer[i] = 0; // add a null char at the end.
printf("%s",buffer); // print using %s format specifier.
```

Comment: @OP: You also need to make the size related change as Gregory mentions.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to allocate `size + 1` bytes to make room for the terminating NULL character:

```
buffer = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*buffer));
```

then before printing make sure the string is NULL terminated: `buffer[size] = '\0';`

finally you're not using printf correctly, it should be

```
printf("%s", buffer);
```

see [printf manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Answer (score 1):

These two strings walk into a bar:

The first string says, "I think I'll have a beer quag fulk boorg jdk^CjfdLk jk3s d#f67howe%^U r89nvy~~owmc63^Dz x.xvcu"

"Please excuse my friend," the second string says, "He isn't null-terminated."

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be waiting for a NULL character at the end of file, you should really be waiting for an EOF (End of file) character instead.

Change this line:

```
      while(((ch = fgetc(fp)) != NULL)
```

To this:

```
      while(((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
```